Flickering when setting monitor below 165hz
I have a 165Hz monitor, when I set the frequency lower than 165Hz (such as 144, 60, etc) I get some flickering in the bottom part of the screen.
Is this a hardware issue? If it's a software issue can I fix it? How?
